# Custom validation for two fields with same validation but slightly different

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the scope that causes code smell:

```
validates :email, uniqueness: { scope: :client_id }, if: Proc.new {|u| u.active? and !u.email.blank? }
validates :companyemail, uniqueness: { scope: :client_id }, if: Proc.new {|u| u.active? and !u.companyemail.blank? }
```

Here's what I've tried, but it causes my tests to fail saying the email fields have already been taken:

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << 'has already been taken' if record.active? and !attribute.blank?
  end
end

validates :email, :companyemail, uniqueness: { scope: :client_id }, email: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the two lines using [`with_options`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html):

Example:

```
with_options uniqueness: { scope: :client_id }, if: Proc.new { |u| u.active? && u.email } do 
  validates :email
  validates :companyemail
end
```

Comment: that doesn't test if companyemail is present, i need it to test if email is unique if the email is there, and the companyemail is unique if its there

Comment: So, could you add `presence: true`?  Apologies, I'm now not quite following the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks when I read your code that this validator should fail every time the record is active and the email address is present.

Did you look at using the `allow_blank: true` option? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#:allow_blank

maybe something like:

```
validates :email,: companyemail uniqueness: { scope: :client_id },  if: "record.active?", allow_blank: true
```